# Post data not being sent when it comes from dynamically added input field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I have a form to register an unlimited number of telephone nums in which I dynamically add some more input fields as the users needs it, so it is defined as (using Laravel html helpers):

```
<h3>Telefone(s):</h3> <a id="add-tel" class="btn btn-danger" data-qtdtels="1">+</a>
<div class="row">
<div id="cad-telefone" class="col-md-12 text-center">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="ddi1">Código internacional (DDI):</label>
            {{ Form::number('ddi1', 55, array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'DDI' )) }}

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="ddd1">Código regional (DDD):</label>
            {{ Form::number('ddd1', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'DDD' )) }}

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="numero1">Número do telefone</label>
            {{ Form::text('numero1', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'maxlength' => '20', 'placeholder' => 'Nro Telefone' )) }}

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Whenever the button with id `add-tel` is pressed, it runs the script which adds the extra input fields, notice the `name` of the input field is defined according to the number of inputs:

```
$("#add-tel").on("click", function(){

    // qtdtels = the number of input fields
    var qtdtels = parseInt($(this).attr("data-qtdtels"));
    qtdtels += 1;
    $(this).attr("data-qtdtels", qtdtels);
    qtdtels = qtdtels.toString();

    var text = "<br><div class=\"row\">";

    text += "<div class=\"col-md-4\">";
    text += "<input class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"DDI\" name=\"ddi" + qtdtels + "\" value=\"55\" type=\"number\">";
    text += "</div>";

    text += "<div class=\"col-md-4\">";
    text += "<input class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"DDD\" name=\"ddd" + qtdtels + "\" type=\"number\">";
    text += "</div>";

    text += "<div class=\"col-md-4\">";
    text += "<input class=\"form-control\" maxlength=\"20\" placeholder=\"Nro telefone\" name=\"numero" + qtdtels + "\" type=\"text\">";
    text += "</div>";

    text += "</div>";
    $(text).appendTo("#cad-telefone");

});
```

The process runs normally on client side and the new inputs are given. The problem is, when I submit the code, on the `$request` it is only posted the fields `ddi1`,`ddd1`,`numero1`. All other dynamically added fields like `ddiX`,`dddX`,`numeroX` are not present. How to make it so I can add more input fields to the `POST`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML created within `#add-tel` `click` handler is not appended to an existing `<form>` element within `document`. The generated HTML is appended to `div#cad-telefone`. When an existing `<form>` is submitted the dynamically created HTML including `<input>` elements are not child nodes of the the existing `<form>` elements at HTML.

You can append the HTML to an existing `<form>` element in `document`, or create and append a new `<form>` for each collection of HTML `<input>` elements then append the generated HTML to the new `<form>` element.

Comment: Thanks, it was that. I thought that only by adding it inside the limits of `<form>...</form>` would be enough but wasn't the case.